# Docker keep hostname available even though container is not running

Tags: docker, varnish

I've got the following issue while using Docker and Varnish.

My `docker-compose.yml` file has the following 2 containers defined

```
varnish:
   image: varnish
   network: test
my-app:
   image: my-app-image
   network: test
```

My varnish VCL has the following config:

```
backend myApp {
    .host = "my-app";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/percolate-health-check";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 4s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}

backend fallback { ...fallback backend settings }
```

Now the current issue I'm experiencing is.
container my-app goes down. Network name `my-app` is also gone.
This in turn crashes Varnish because my-app cannot be resolved.

Is there some way for a Docker hostname keep existing even though the container is down?
Or how should I handle this issue with Varnish / Docker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a backend is no longer available, Varnish will usually not crash. Instead an `HTTP 503` error will be returned.

## Grace mode

If there's no fallback container you can use grace mode to keep serving stale data while the backend is down. Have a look at https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/vcl-grace.html#misbehaving-servers to see a VCL example.

## Directors

If you do have a fallback backend, or just multiple backends in general, you can use *directors* to loadbalance between the backends: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/vcl-backends.html#directors.

There area many types of directors. See 
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#varnish-directors-module for an overview

Comment: This is correct, but I'm getting VCL compilation errors due to host not being able to be resolved: `Backend host '"my-app"' could not be resolved to an IP address:` This is due to docker removing the hostname once my backend crashes.

Comment: I'm also currently using a fallback director to fallback to the original app when my docker container crashes. But due to the VCL compilation error this won't work :(

Comment: @StijnBernards the only solution I have for you is using **dynamic backends**, unfortunately that's a Varnish Enterprise feature: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/

Comment: @StijnBernards a more important question is: why is this container down? Are you using standalone Docker or are you orchestrating in Kubernetes? Kubernetes have built-in solutions for your problem.

Comment: I'm using standard docker without Kubernetes or a Docker Swarm set up.
My container barely goes down, but I want to fix the cases where it suddenly does.
I think my question might be more Linux/Networking related. Maybe there is a solution to keeping the hostname accessible for varnish by routing it to localhost via /etc/hosts if docker overrides /etc/hosts?

Comment: @StijnBernards If you have to manage multiple containers using standalone Docker and you want to make sure the origin is started before Varnish, you can use `docker-compse` and use the `depends_on` directive. See https://gist.github.com/ThijsFeryn/166a19b53cf9b0fdf452632462ee7417 for an example.

If Varnish can't start because the origin hostname doesn't resolve, it means both of your containers are down. `docker-compose` could make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm using docker-compose. Varnish is unable to start if only one of my backends is down, even though I'm using a fallback director.
Here's my full current VCL: https://gist.github.com/stijnbernards/baf87e288acfe1ef1ed3522ef888f1a6